# Does any company manufacture American AC power plugs with insulated pins?

Tags: ac, safety, mains, insulation

In Australia and some other places, good-quality AC power plugs have "insulated pins". This means that there is a short length of insulation covering the base of the pins. Darren Yates [writes](http://darrenyates.com.au/2014/12/tech-safe-christmas/3195) that this has been legally required in Australia since 2005.

Insulated pins are a useful safety feature; they help prevent people from accidentally touching live pins and getting electrocuted.

In the US, AC power plugs (such as NEMA 1 and NEMA 5 plugs) seem to normally not have insulated pins. That is why Etotal IntelliHouse [writes](http://www.etotal.dk/page/world-standards-electricity-around-the-world-54/) that they are not very safe.

Does any company manufacture NEMA 1 or NEMA 5 plugs with insulated pins?

(I thank the user [tronixstuff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/is-it-safe-to-use-a-dc-power-adapter-that-isnt-ul-listed-or-csa-certified#4773) for [inspiring](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/is-it-safe-to-use-a-dc-power-adapter-that-isnt-ul-listed-or-csa-certified#4773) this question.)

Comment: An aside: I have precisely one non-insulated-pin UK plug. It is fitted to a 55 year old vacuum cleaner. I haven't seen any others since the 1970s...

Comment: Indeed, as a EU citizen I was shocked (not literally !) to see a video of someone in the US plugging in an adapter and I was surprised how easy it must be to touch the live metal parts of the plug. I guess due to the 110 VAC most people make that mistake only once but live to not repeat it ;-) Sorry for not being able to answe your question :-)

Comment: I've lived in the USA for a few years and although I am familiar with insulated plugs from other parts of the world, I've never seen an insulated plug here.

Comment: Never seen such a thing. A sideways butter knife will always create fireworks. In fact that's how some of us learned about electricity (the ones that survived)..

Comment: Given the thickness of the pins (thin folded brass sheet?) I'd be surprised if you could insulate them reliably(taking wear into account) without compromising the pin's strength.

Comment: @Brian I'd never taken much notice before but just took a scribe to a plug from Agilent Australia and it's quite a hard paint-like coating just applied to the outside of the pin. I don't have a way to measure but giving it a fingernail test against a PCB I'd say it's the same thickness as 1oz copper (35 micron odd after a Google).

Comment: [AC Power Supply Cord 12A 125V 2-pin Right-Angled Insulated pin Japan PSe Plug PHP-227R](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/AC-Power-Supply-Cord-12A-125V_106912162.html)

Comment: @Tut: Nice find! After seeing your comment, I did a Google image search for [ japanese plug insulated pins ] and found a company which makes _grounded_ Japanese AC power plugs. See [here](http://www.yunhuanelectric.com/Japan-pse-jet-power-cords-3-prong.html) and look at the photo at the bottom-left corner of the page.

Comment: @unforgettableid Japan has a slightly weird system where half the time you have to ground your appliance yourself by taking the ground wire from the plug and attaching it to the grounding post on the socket: http://www.6moons.com/audioreviews/triodekit/powercord.jpg It defies the purpose of a plug in my opinion ...

Comment: It's now almost 8 years from this original post and I'm currently in an electrical safety conference (ESW 2023) and the keynote speaker raised this same issue: it is possible to get an electric shock by touching the pins. We had some table discussions on why this kind of insulated pins are not available and the end result was that "probably adding the insulation will reduce the cross-sectional area of metal part so that it won't pass the heating test". In my opinion, it could be still possible to apply insulation to phone chargers, luminaires and other gadgets with << 2 A current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [Tut's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176081/does-any-company-manufacture-american-ac-power-plugs-with-insulated-pins#comment360523_176081), I did a Google image search for `[ japanese plug insulated pins ]` and found a company which sells grounded Japanese AC power plugs.

Here's a photo of a "Japan JIS C8303 15A AC Power Cord with Insulated Neutral/Live Plug Pins".  I found it [here](http://www.yunhuanelectric.com/Japan-pse-jet-power-cords-3-prong.html):  scroll down and see the photo at the bottom-left corner of the page.

It looks like it might fit in American outlets.

[image: Japan JIS C8303 15A AC Power Cord with Insulated Neutral/Live Plug Pins]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so- I've never seen such a thing and if you look at the internal design of a typical receptacle I don't think that such a plug could be reliably backward compatible unless the insulated length was only a couple mm and the thickness very thin. Given the enormous installed base of receptacles and extension cords, such a change is unlikely to be popularly accepted.

It is possible to get even an adult-sized finger under even a normal plug, so such a design would not pass the UL 4mm baby-finger requirement if it was to be introduced today.

Here is a photo of an AC adapter plugged into a power bar receptacle. There is 120V present on the pins (verified by voltmeter) and the finger is an adult one (mine, just before my death by electrocution).

[image]

It's worse again if the pins are bent, which is pretty easy with ungrounded cord ends. Especially if some cretin pulls the plug out by yanking on the cord at an obtuse angle.

Comment: I went to NY for a hol 4mo ago and stayed in timesSquare. A power outlet for the TV was just hanging out (1/2 plugged in and just ..resting), supported with electrical tape while exposing the connections.  fingers of 4yo and 8yo are oh so inquisitive... it was quickly removed and coiled up

Comment: That's pretty much how I feel when I go to Mexico- so many open exposed mains wires... I guess it gets a few people now and then, and the survivors learn.

Answer (score 3):

I've lived in the USA my entire life, and have never seen that type of insulated plug here.  I also haven't spoken to a single adult person here that hasn't been shocked by 120V sometime in their lives!  At least, that I'm aware of :)

I recently put some new outlets into my house.  The are different than the old "standard" outlets, although you might not notice.  Basically, the prongs of the plug have to penetrate deeper into the outlet before they make electrical contact.  And they're held more tightly, since the contact length is shorter.  I assume this new design is mandated for safety.

I think we (USA'ers) get complacent because we don't have to be that careful with our mains voltages.  If I'm wondering if wires are live, and I'm feeling brave,  I'll quickly swipe my finger tips across them and see if I get shocked :)  **I don't recommend this!**  And, for the record, most people here would think think it's a dumb idea, too.

Comment: and that is bad :( 115V can just as easily kill as 230V.. that's why the LVD is set around 75Vdc,50Vac. I have been shocked by 115V, 230V, 540Vdc, 600Vdc and am still here. the adage that it is lower so safer is unfortunately very common and very misplaced

Comment: @JonRB:  what's an "LVD"?

Comment: Low voltage directive. A UK legislation that was adopted by the EU. Anything below 50Vac (or 75Vdc) is deemed extra low voltage and no special precautions are needed. 50vac ->1000v are then deemed low voltage and certain precautions are needed